# change vertical spacing number and title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

How does one change (decrease in this case) the vertical spacing between the title number and the titlename in this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright}
{\hspace*{\fill}\resizebox{!}{50pt}{\thechapter}}
{20pt}
{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{test}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

which produces this

[image: example]

I find the vertical spacing between the number and the name of the title to be too large, how do I adjust that easily? (I tried using a raisebox with negative values but this lowered the whole title not just the number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the separation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright}
{\hspace*{\fill}\resizebox{!}{50pt}{\thechapter}}
{0pt}
{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{test}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

See also `titlesec` documentation:  `{sep}` *This space is vertical in display shape*

Comment: Thank you, I first made the title in block, so then it was horizontal spacing. I failed to realize that it would be vertical spacing in display.